# Principle of setting 'hash_bucket_size' parameter?

Tags: tensorflow

**Question 1**:

In [`wide_n_deep_tutorial.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py), there is a hyper-parameter named `hash_bucket_size` for both `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket` and `tf.feature_column.crossed_column` methods, and the value is `hash_bucket_size=1000`.

But why 1000? How to set this parameter ?

**Question 2**:
The second question about `crossed_columns`, that is,

`crossed_columns = [ 
tf.feature_column.crossed_column( ["education", "occupation"], hash_bucket_size=1000), 
tf.feature_column.crossed_column( [age_buckets, "education", "occupation"], hash_bucket_size=1000), 
tf.feature_column.crossed_column( ["native_country", "occupation"], hash_bucket_size=1000) ]`

in `wide_n_deep_tutorial.py`,

Why choose `["education", "occupation"]`, `[age_buckets, "education", "occupation"]` and `["native_country", "occupation"]` as `crossed_columns`, are there any rule of thumb ?

Comment: Hi @feng1122, on StackOverflow it is best to avoid asking several questions in one, you will get better answers and it will make it easier to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For the hash_bucket*

The general idea is that ideally the result of the hash functions should not result in any collisions (otherwise you/the algorithm would not be able to distinguish between two cases). Hence the 1000 is in this case 'just' a value. If you look at the unique entries for occupation and country (16 and 43) you'll see that this number is high enough:

```
edb@lapelidb:/tmp$ cat  adult.data | cut -d , -f 7 | sort  | uniq -c  | wc -l
16
edb@lapelidb:/tmp$ cat  adult.data | cut -d , -f 14 | sort  | uniq -c  | wc -l
43
```

*Feature crossing*

I think the rule of thumb there is that crossing makes sense if the combination of the features actually has meaning. In this example education and occupation are linked. As for the second one it probably make sense to define people as 'junior engineer with a ph.d' vs 'senior cleaning staff without a degree'.  Another typical example you see quite often is the crossing of longitude and latitude since they have more meaning together than individually.

Comment: _For the hash_bucket_  Can I use the rule that `the smallest integer (say: 100, 1000, 10000, 100000) than 10 * unique entries` ? For example, the feature `A` has 120 unique entries, so the `hash_bucket_size=10000` make sense?

Comment: _Feature crossing_ It seem that it needs time and labor consuming feature engineering ?  Just imagine that there are hundreds of features, how to decide cross columns ?

Comment: For hash_bucket, the best thing you could do is actually test it, simply create the hash of all your input and make sure no duplicates arise. As for feature crossing, if you have hundreds of features, that will require some time, just remember there's no free lunch, this will require some work and some understanding of the data.

Answer (score 8):

Regarding the `hash_bucket_size`: if you set it too low, there will be many hash collisions, where different categories will be mapped to the same bucket, forcing the neural network to use other features to distinguish them. If you set it too high then you will use a lot of RAM for nothing: I am assuming that you will wrap the `categorical_column_with_hash_bucket()` in an `embedding_column()` (as you generally should), in which case the `hash_bucket_size` will determine the number of rows of the embedding matrix.

The probability of a collision if there are k categories is approximately equal to: `1 - exp(-k*(k-1)/2/hash_bucket_size)` ([source](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/)), so if there are 40 categories and you use `hash_bucket_size=1000`, the probability is surprisingly high: about 54%! To convince yourself, try running `len(np.unique(np.random.randint(1000, size=40)))` several times (it picks 40 random numbers between 0 and 999 and counts how many unique numbers there are), and you will see that the result is quite often less than 40. You can use this equation to choose a value of `hash_bucket_size` that does not cause too many collisions.

That said, if there are just a couple collisions, it's probably not going to be too bad in practice, as the neural network will still be able to use other features to distinguish the colliding categories. The best option may be to experiment with different values of `hash_bucket_size` to find the value below which performance starts to degrade, then increase it by 10-20% to be safe.